# Showing line numbers in IPython/Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Error reports from most language kernels running in IPython/Jupyter Notebooks indicate the line on which the error occurred, but (at least by default) no line numbers are shown in notebooks.

How is it possible to add the line numbers to IPython/Jupyter Notebooks?

Comment: It would be also usefull to change the default behavior of the ipython notebook such that it displays line numbers by default

Answer (score 214, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> toggles line numbers in the CodeMirror area.  See the QuickHelp for other keyboard shortcuts.

In more details <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>M</kbd> (or <kbd>ESC</kbd>) bring you to command mode, then pressing the <kbd>L</kbd> keys should toggle the visibility of current cell line numbers. In more recent notebook versions <kbd>Shift-L</kbd> should toggle for all cells.

If you can't remember the shortcut, bring up the command palette <kbd>Ctrl-Shift+P</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd+Shift+P</kbd> on Mac), and search for "line numbers"), it should allow to toggle and show you the shortcut.

Comment: For Ipython 3 (Jupyter), in command mode (Esc), you just have to press "L" to toggle line numbers

Comment: Is there a way to add line number automatically to all the cells in Jupiter

Comment: Use `Ctrl-m` `h` to show all keyboard shortcuts in ipython notebook. Alternatively you can click on `QuckHelp` at the top to show the shortcuts

Comment: `Ctrl-Shift+P` for the win

Comment: you know if posible run some comand in cell directly ?, i haven't access to toolbar o normal options on aws glue notebooks

Answer (score 89):

On IPython 2.2.0, just typing l (lowercase L) on command mode (activated by typing Esc) works.  See [Help] - [Keyboard Shortcuts] for other shortcuts.

Also, you can set default behavior to display line numbers by [editing `custom.js`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197471/how-to-display-line-numbers-in-ipython-notebook-code-cell-by-default)

Comment: I don't understand how this answer was not accepted (maybe posted too late?), because this is the correct one if you don't use CodeMirror but just IPython Notebook. EDIT: in fact IPython Notebook uses CodeMirror. So both answers are correct. Learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: thanks, this worked for jupyter notebook in chrome.  this seems easiest...

Answer (score 79):

Select the Toggle Line Number Option from the  <kbd>View</kbd> -> <kbd>Toggle Line Number</kbd>.

[image: The menu looks like this]

Comment: I can't believe it was this easy. Not sure why it's not on by default when they give errors by line. Would be nice if the notebook just highlighted the line that gave the error.

Comment: This is no longer in the view. :/ have to search for it in the command palette.

Comment: @Kaito When your code is a bit more complex, there is maybe not one unique line which led to the error, or the error came from code which you wrote in another cell or imported. Thus I think the highlighting approach is not practicable.

Answer (score 16):

1. Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> so the left part becomes blue.

[image]

2. Then press <kbd>L</kbd>. It works!
3. If you want to hide them, use the same algorithm.
4. If you want to impact all Jupiter rows, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, while the left part is blue.

Comment: I don't find that toggling line numbers in the last cell affects all cells. But isn't that what you're saying in point 4?

Comment: @NerdOnTour - true, I stay corrected and I have edited (about 13+ months later). To impact all rows, Shift should be pressed, when "L" is pressed.

Answer (score 11):

To turn line numbers on by default in all cells at startup I recommend [this link](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/11/show-line-numbers-by-default-in-ipython-notebook/). I quote:

> 1. Navigate to your jupyter config directory, which you can find by typing the following at the command line:
>
>    ```
>    jupyter --config-dir
>    ```
> 2. From there, open or create the `custom` folder.
> 3. In that folder, you should find a `custom.js` file. If there isn’t one, you should be able to create one. Open it in a text editor and
>      add this code:
>
>    ```
>    define([
>        'base/js/namespace',
>        'base/js/events'
>        ],
>        function(IPython, events) {
>            events.on("app_initialized.NotebookApp",
>                function () {
>                    IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineNumbers = true;
>                }
>            );
>        }
>    );
>    ```

Comment: you know if posible run some comand in cell directly ?, i haven't access to toolbar o normal options on aws glue notebooks

Answer (score 9):

Here is how to know active shortcut (depending on your OS and notebook version, it might change)

`Help > Keyboard Shortcuts > toggle line numbers`

On OSX running ipython3 it was `ESC L`

Answer (score 7):

For me, `ctrl + m` is used to save the webpage as png, so it does not work properly. But I find another way.

On the toolbar, there is a bottom named **open the command paletee**, you can click it and type in the line, and you can see the toggle cell line number here.

Answer (score 7):

In Jupyter Lab 2.1.5, it is <kbd>View</kbd> -> <kbd>Show Line Numbers</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Adding to ronnefeldt's accepted answer: <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> toggles line numbers in *all* cells. This works in JupyterLab 1.0.0 and in Jupyter Notebooks.

Answer (score 4):

To show line numbers by default in Jupyter lab,

- Click on the menu `Settings` → `Advanced Settings Editor` (or use the shortcut `control`+`,`). An environment with three columns will appear: the settings category, `System Defaults`, and `User Preferences`.
- Select the category `notebook`
- Set the key `"lineNumbers"` to `true` in the `"codeCellConfig"` options.

For example, (assuming no other user configured settings),:

```js
{
    "codeCellConfig": {
        "lineNumbers": true,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also find `Toggle Line Numbers` under `View` on the top toolbar of the Jupyter notebook in your browser.
This adds/removes the lines numbers in **all** notebook cells.

For me, <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> only added/removed the line numbers of the active cell.

Answer (score -3):

1.press esc to enter the command mode
2.perss l(it L in lowcase) to show the line number

Comment: This was posted 3 years ago already https://stackoverflow.com/a/26174059/3001626 , why repost on the same thread?