# How to display line numbers in IPython Notebook code cell by default

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like my default display for IPython notebook code cells to include line numbers.

I learned from [Showing line numbers in IPython/Jupyter Notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979667/ipython-notebook-line-number) that I can toggle this with ctrl-M L, which is great, but manual. In order to include line numbers by default, I would need to add something to my ipython_notebook_config.py file. Unless I've missed something, there is not an explanation of how to do this in the documentation.

Comment: For people in Latest 2021 versions, just add this in your advanced settings.json 
`{ "codeCellConfig": { "lineNumbers": true}
}`

Comment: @shivam13juna thanks a lot, nothing from answers below worked !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your `custom.js` file (location depends on your OS) put

`IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineNumbers = true;`

If you can't find custom.js, you can just search for it, but generally it will be in your profile_default folder. If it doesn't exist, create the file at `$(ipython locate profile)/static/custom/custom.js`

If for whatever reason that doesn't work, you can always edit the `custom.js` file in the `site-packages/IPython/html/static/custom/` in the same way.

Comment: Very cool; works. One additional thing I've learned trying to get this to work: at least for me, despite the comment in the default custom.js file (“Placeholder for custom user javascript mainly to be overridden in profile/static/custom/custom.js”), the file must be located directly in the profile directory (for me, ~/.ipython/profile_default/).

Comment: Awesome! I learned some things as well :D. It would be great if you could accept the answer, cheers.

Comment: @WilliamDenman, this does not work anymore in the new Jupyter notebook, any idea why or better yet, how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I'll be honest, your comment is the first I've heard of Jupyter. It looks really cool! Unfortunately, I am no longer using Python/iPython on a daily basis. Have moved to .NET/C#/VB (for work). So I won't be able to help you. I suggest, if my answer does not work, post a new SO question. I'm sure someone more knowledgeable will be able to answer it.

Comment: @Shahar (and future readers), this does in fact still work on Jupyter notebook, at least 3.1.0.

Comment: @jedwards, I don't know why, but neither editing `.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js` nor editing `site-packages/IPython/html/static/custom/custom.js` to include `IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineNumbers = true;` works for me on Python 2.7.6 IPython 3.1.0.

Comment: you know if posible run some comand in cell directly ?, i haven't access  to toolbar  o normal options on aws glue notebooks

Answer (score 47):

**(For Jupyter 4+)** In the latest Jupyter versions, they have [documented](https://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html) the place to make config changes. So basically, in the Jupyter update, they've removed the concept of profiles, so the `custom.js` file location is now `.jupyter/custom/custom.js`, depending on where your `.jupyter` folder is. So if you don't have a `custom` folder or the `custom.js` file, just create them, then put these lines into the newly created file:

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
    ], 
    function(IPython, events) {
        events.on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", 
            function () {
                require("notebook/js/cell").Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineNumbers = true;
            }
        );
    }
);
```

The above is for setting line numbers to **all your cell types** at the same time. Code, Markdown and Raw cells will all get line numbers if you do this. If you want line numbers **only for code cells**, there is a simpler approach. Select a code cell, open the Chrome/Firefox JavaScript console, type the following lines:

```
var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();
var config = cell.config;
var patch = {
    CodeCell:{
        cm_config:{lineNumbers:true}
    }
}
config.update(patch)
```

Then reload the page. These changes persist because Jupyter will create a json config file in `.jupyter/nbconfig` to store them. This method is from [this page](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/frontend_config.html) of the documentation, so read the docs for more config changes that you can make.

---

*(old answer)*

In the latest version of IPython Notebook (v3.1.0), go to `~/.ipython/<profile_name>/static/custom/custom.js` and add these lines:

```js
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
    ], 
    function(IPython, events) {
        events.on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", 
            function () {
                IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineNumbers = true;
            }
        );
    }
);
```

The `IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineNumbers = true;` line alone will not work as it needs to load the IPython.Cell object before it tries this. Adding this line alone will cause an undefined error in the console. You need to encase it in the event handler as shown.

@William-Denman's code might have worked for an earlier version, but now you will need to do this.

<strike>**EDIT:** The line of code right in the middle has to be changed to `require("notebook/js/cell").Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineNumbers = true;` for the latest version of IPython/Jupyter (**IPython 4.0.0, Jupyter 4.0.6**). The old `IPython.Cell` object will also work, but your web console will throw a deprecation warning, so you can expect the old line to not be supported in future versions.</strike>

Also, in the latest IPython/Jupyter, which I'm running using the [WinPython portable](https://winpython.github.io/), I couldn't find the `custom.js` file within the profile folder. I found it (after *much* searching) in `WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom`. I don't know if this is a WinPython thing or a Jupyter thing. If someone has Jupyter (latest version) installed normally (using pip or whatever) and can still find the `custom.js` file in the profile folder, please comment.

Comment: For me using v3.2.0,  the accepted answer does not work but this does. Thanks.

Comment: @Mindstormer619, thanks. This solution works and should be regarded as the correct answer.

Comment: consider moving to the top of the answer the more recent, correct approach :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Will do :D

Comment: `define` method must be following after `require` method. If there is a `require` method after `define`, `Mismatched anonymous define() module` error will be raised.

Comment: Hi @fx-kirin, I believe this whole thing is a non-issue in the latest version of Jupyter. Just hit `Shift+L`. This toggles in all cells and persists the setting.

Comment: you know if posible run some comand in cell directly ?, i haven't access to toolbar o normal options on aws glue notebooks

Answer (score 6):

### Above didn't work for me in 2018

I found that inside `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json` I needed to add to add the following lines:

```
"CodeCell": {
  "cm_config": {
  "lineNumbers": true
}
```

inside the object that was there. So the final object would look like:

```
{
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineNumbers": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen. In the current version of Jupyter, you can just hit Shift+L on a cell (in Command Mode) to toggle line numbers and persist the setting. Going through the config files manually is unneeded :)

Comment: @Mindstormer619 Haha, thanks! I've been trying out vim for Jupyter and got sick of toggling line numbers for each cell... Didn't realize it was that easy to just turn them all on or off. Eventually ended up with what I said, but your way is easier =)

Comment: I'm using jupyter-vim-binding and this method was easy and worked for me, thanks!

Comment: can modify this running a cell ?