# How to enable line number upon start-up in jupyter-vim-binding?

Tags: vim, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyter-vim-binding. I can toggle line numbers with `C-o, Shift-L`. How can I enable line number upon start-up (i.e. when creating a new code cell)? I'm aware of the customization js file but I'm afraid of breaking the current setup, so would like answers from more seasoned users.

Comment: autocommand might help: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html

Comment: For normal vim, it would be `:au BufEnter *.* :set nu<CR>`. Put this line in your ~/.vimrc. When you open any file, you will see the line numbers.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197471/how-to-display-line-numbers-in-ipython-notebook-code-cell-by-default

Comment: New, better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55035981/230468

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Jupyter Notebook docs](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frontend_config.html) show an example to change the default indentation of code cells. You can follow the instructions on that page, but instead pass the `lineNumbers` argument:

```
var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();
var config = cell.config;
var patch = {
    CodeCell:{
        cm_config:{lineNumbers:true}
    }
}
config.update(patch)
```

You should still be able to toggle line-numbers with the `jupyter-vim-binding` shortcut.

Comment: Thanks. I pasted the code you provided in the Javascript console and it worked.